# Зачем нужны интерфейсы?

Tags: php, интерфейс

Друзья, неоднократно задавался вопросом и задавал вопрос здесь, беспокоит и не даёт покоя мысль о том, зачем нужны интерфейсы в php на пример.

Есть кучи примеров, где объяснятся лишь только то что, они задают жёстко типизированную структуру для других классов которые имплементируют и обязаны реализовывать публичные методы, но толку, неужели профит только в этом, бороздя статьи по интерфейсам были такие мнения что они позволяют обойти НЕмножественное наследование, то есть как? Объясните пожалуйста, элементарный пример связи, как это происходит?

Допустим есть интерфейс с одним методом. Имплементирующие его классы реализуют его под свои нужды как им хотелось бы, но везде по разному, и это всё? Допустим наследовались от того класса, который имплементировал интерфейс, дальше что?

*Обновление*

```
<?php
interface lol
    {
    public

    function game();
    }

class outlol implements lol

    {
    public

    function game()
        {
        return "outlol";
        }
    }

class inlol implements lol

    {
    public

    function game()
        {
        return "inlol";
        }
    }

class anon

    {
    public

    function you(inlol $inlol)
        {
        echo $inlol->game();
        }

    public

    function to(outlol $outlol)
        {
        echo $outlol->game();
        }
    }

$obj = new anon();
$obj->you(new inlol());
echo "<br />";
$obj->to(new outlol());
echo "<br />";
```

Вернёт соответствующие строки, это и есть пример реализации интерфесов?

Comment: Профит в полиморфизме, может с него начать понимание?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

С интерфейсами можно решать много различных проблем в тех языках, где нет утиной типизации.

Например. Можно объявить интерфейс, который будет описывать вывод элемента на экран. Дальше, написать несколько классов, которые реализуют этот интерфейс. Потом создать общую функцию вывода, которая будет получать одним с параметров указатель на класс/объект вывода. Если бы интерфейсов не было, пришлось эти все классы наследовать от одного общего предка. А это не всегда возможно. И если нужно стороннему классу добавить подобную функциональность - очень быстро пишется наследник с нужной реализацией.

Второй плюс интерфейсов - класс может реализовывать много интерфейсов. Это актуально там, где нет множественного наследования.

Третий плюс интерфейсов - междуязыковое общение (я правда не знаю, работает ли это в php, но точно работает в C/C++, Delphi, .NET). Интерфейс может быть описан в одном месте, а реализован на совсем другом языке. И это не мешает использовать его. Сама Windows активно использует интерфейсы.

Comment: я только что прокомментировал пример чуть выше, я думаю твой ответ схож с моим примером

Answer (score 11):

Рассматривайте интерфейс как контракт для класса на реализацию ряда методов. Смотреть нужно не со стороны самого класса, реализующего интерфейс, а со стороны классов, которые его используют. Если какой-то класс реализует интерфейс, то другие классы будут уверены, что в этом классе есть все методы, перечисленные в интерфейсе, и они могут их использовать. В качестве примера можно привести интерфейс `Дверь`. Всё, что нужно знать программе, использующей `Дверь`, это то, что её можно открыть и закрыть. При этом совершенно не важно, будет ли это обычная дверь, двустворчатая двеь или дверь банковского сейфа. При этом принципиальное отличие от наследования в данном случае состоит в том, что класс, реализующий интерфейс `Дверь`, может реализовывать другие интерфейсы, и даже наследоваться от какого-нибудь класса, избегая при этом проблем множественного наследования.

По поводу множественного наследования. Предположим у нас есть классы `A` и `B`, в каждом из которых реализован метод `doSth()`. От них наследуется класс `C`. При этом возникает проблема: какой метод вызывать при вызове `C.doSth()` - `A.doSth()` или `B.doSth()`? Ведь оба метода унаследовались, и теперь каждый раз при вызове `C.doSth()` нужно явно указывать, метод какого из классов-предков использовать. Совсем другое дело если `A` и `B` интерфейсы. Если класс `C` реализует интерфейсы `A` и `B`, то в нём гарантированно будет метод `doSth()`, при этом не будет никаких коллизий, так как в интерфейсах нельзя реализовывать методы.